# How to assert image source in rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, automated-tests

My page should contain an image that looks like

```
<img src="some_long_url">
```

How would you test for that using **assert_select?** I want to check for the presence of an imgage with **src="some long url "**.

I already have tried this :

```
assert_select "img[src=?]", /amazon.com/
```

Because the url of source is dynamic except **amazon.com** that's why i want my src attribute to contain amazon.com and neglect remaining with regular expression.

Which means i want my src to contain some specific string.
But it gives following **error:**

> Expected at least 1 element matching "img[src="(?-mix:amazon.com)"]",
>   found 0

I am working in Rails 4.2 and using the built-in test framework.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
assert_select "img" do
  assert_select "[src=?]", /amazon/
end
```

? From the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select)

Comment: What does your full test look like?

Comment: Right, but in order to help me help you, what does your test look like? The error message you're getting is because you never defined `img` in your test. I don't know what your test looks like, so I can't help you define `img`.

Comment: here its short form >>>>>>>>>>test "z" do
    get "/personal_settings/personal_info"
    assert_response :success
    assert_match "img['src']", /amaz/
end

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I misunderstood your original question, my bad. Updating my answer.